Uberjar and fatjar look the same?
The uberjar and fatjar tags look the same. uberjar has 185 uses, and fatjar has 183 (with some overlap). The wiki for uberjar has existed for 16 years, while fatjar has none:

An Uber JAR (AKA fat JAR or super JAR) is a JAR file that contains both the package and all its dependencies in one single JAR file.
The advantage is that you can distribute an Uber JAR and not care at all whether or not dependencies are installed at the destination, as an Uber JAR actually has no dependencies.

I'm leaning towards making fatjar an alias, but I'm not sure which term is more prevalent.

Presumably relevant, but doesn't have either tag: What are the differences between uberJar, fatJar and shadowJar in Gradle?

I did a bit of research (aka Googling).  There isn't a (consensus) preferred alternative for these two terms, but I've seen many sources that imply that they mean the same thing.  I haven't seen any sources that say where or when the terms were respectively introduced, or by whom, so we can't make a call based on first use.  I don't think it really matters which one is the alias, but (IMO) it would be a good idea to do a tag merge.

Not a great metric, but What is a fat JAR? was closed as a duplicate of What is an uber JAR file?. Though personally, I'd make fatjar the primary tag, and uberjar a synonym, because I've only ever heard of and used fatjar, but that's just my opinion. I think in the end, which tag is the main one and which is the synonym is irrelevant, as long as they're linked together, this mess is cleared up.

"fatjar" is shorter and seems easier to say to me; and it's probably slightly harder to find people willing to parse some kind of problematic meaning out of it.

I merged fatjar into uberjar and created a synonym [fatjar] -> [uberjar]
updating post history, 149 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 139 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 130 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'fatjar': [fatjar] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 315
tag remapping of [uberjar] and [fatjar] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
7 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
23 tracked tag badges were remapped!

I merged this direction because fatjar had no tag wiki components and I wanted to preserve the one in uberjar so this was the only way to do that. It'd be trivial for a moderator to swap the synonym direction if we come to a clear consensus that fatjar is the better parent tag.
